# extracting frames using FFMPEG?

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, frame

I'm trying to write code to extract 16 frames from a video file using ffmpeg (or openCV - open to suggestions) and python but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get started.
Can I use ffmpeg command lines directly in python? If so, are there commands to get the length of the clip and frame rate? How can I pull frames at equal intervals?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can get metadata info by using ffprobe, included with ffmpeg.

The Module Subprocess is a way to use tools outside python and return exit status or check Output like in my example below. Then you can assign python variables to the parsed output of ffprobe.
There are security Issues with using shell=True. This will at least get you started, and you can figure out a way to avoid using it later on.

```
import subprocess

dur_check = subprocess.check_output('ffprobe -v error -show_format We\ Code\ Hard.mp4 | grep duration')
duration = dur_check.split('=')[1]
```

Which will return:

```
'192.631667'
```

And then, a little bit different for fps.

```
fps_check = subprocess.check_output('ffprobe We\ Code\ Hard.mp4 2>&1 | grep fps',shell=True)
fps = fps_check.split(' ')[4].strip()
```

Which Returns:

```
'29.97 fps'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking something along those lines.. For example I have to following command line that I want to execute in a loop:
'cmdline = "ffmpeg -i " + file + " -ss 00:00:%d -vframes 1 BPout%d.png" (frametimestamps[i], i)'
Could I similarly call 
'subprocess.check_output(cmdline)' to output a frame?

Comment: You can use either 'check_output' or 'call'. call will return an exit status to determine if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Can I use ffmpeg command lines directly in python?

Yes. I have no experience with Python, but [tink3r's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35688754/1109017) looks like an example to me.

> #### If so, are there commands to get the length of the clip and frame rate?

Yes. Use `ffprobe`.

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration,avg_frame_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=0 input.mp4
avg_frame_rate=24/1
duration=888.000000
```

- This example will get the desired info from the first video stream only; otherwise it will also show entries for audio, etc.
- As the example shows there is no need for additional processes such as `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or anything like that.
- If you want to remove the `avg_frame_rate=` and `duration=` keys then change `nk=0` to `nk=1`.
- Python people like JSON format, right? If that's the case then you can change `-of default=nw=1:nk=0` to `-of json`.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more examples.

> #### How can I pull frames at equal intervals?

You can use the [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect). Example to select one frame every ten seconds:

```
ffmpeg -i -vf "select='not(mod(t\,10))'" -vsync vfr output_%03d.png
```

This will result in `output_001.png`, `output_002.png`, `output_003.png`, etc.

Comment: thank you so much for your helpful response! Managed to figure it all out! :)